# Author of a short story in a compilation or high school textbook for a Sci-Fi extra credit course

Tags: story-identification, authors

The name of the short story was/is "Sanity".

It was about a post-apocalyptic town where everyone was going clinically insane, except one guy who was made the "mayor". During a council meeting, he expresses all these very "sane" ideas to get the town back on its feet only to find the town council is also insane.

My question is: Who was/is the Author?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details.

Comment: There are only two stories called "Sanity" listed in the Internet Scifi Database. Leiber's 'Sanity' looked the best bet but it's about a "World Manager" who's essentially been humoured into thinking he's actually running the world when in fact his staff have merely been tricking him.

Comment: How long ago did you read it?

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=sanity&type=Fiction+Titles - "Sanity Clause" is about an insane Santa, 'Sanity and the Lady' is about a world gone mad after an alien invasion.

Comment: If you have suggestions of what it may be, add an answer. Stop answering in comments.

Comment: @Valorum the one by Leiber seems close enough to give it a shot, actually.

Comment: @Phantom42 - These aren't answers. I'm ruling things out and adding notes to save people wasting their time

Comment: @SQB - Aside from the title, literally no other details match.

Comment: @Valorum Well, mayor/world leader, town council insane/staff has been tricking him. I can see the similarities.

Comment: You are offering titles it may be. Those are answers.

Comment: Valorum has the right author and story. It's been over 30 years since I read it user 14111. I guess in that time I stripped it down to a mayor in some petty little town; but, the World Manager and the tricky, humoring staff is exactly the plot. It's classic Rod Serling type stuff; of which, has obviously left an impression on me to this very day.

Comment: @Valorum why don't you post it as answer now? Wayne has confirmed above.

Comment: @Ayshe - I didn't spot OP's comment since he didn't tag me in :-)

Answer (score 9):

This is [Sanity](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40971) by Fritz Leiber.

> World Manager Carrsbury runs the affairs of the world government in a
> future where the concept of insanity is no longer recognized, even
> though pretty much all of the Earth's inhabitants have a neuroses of
> one sort or another . . . especially in the rarified strata of
> government. Carrsbury, however, is perfectly sane, and upon his
> ascendance to head of state, he sets about a course to replace all of
> government with hand-picked sane individuals trained at his Institute
> of Political Leadership, for the sake of the Earth.
>
> He summons in the General Secretary of the World, the only 'insane'
> official that he has ever felt he had a connection to, to his office
> on the day that the transformation is to begin, to explain what is
> about to take place.
>
> <sub><sup>[Sanity: Synopsis](http://www.scrollsoflankhmar.com/oeuvre:fiction:shortstories:sanity)</sup></sub>